# Connect Android to raspberrypi to use it as Camera

Tags: raspicam

I've looked a lot for the way that to connect Android smart phone to Raspberrypi via USB. Most of articles explain how to stream camera over network ... that means to control Raspberry Pi camera using Android

> what I need is the opposite:
>
> I want to use my Android phone as a camera (connected via USB) to be able to capture images using its camera.

I need all that to avoid the redundancy of webcam and to have better resolution

I'm grateful for any help or suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I searched around and found a similar answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38902/camera-input-from-phone-to-raspberry-pi) to what you were asking, and was done via tethering/wifi. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much ... I trying thus solution ... but I faced another problem ... that when I connect my Android phone to Raspberrypi via USB. .. it consume the power of it because of charging

Comment: That's why I'm trying to stream Android cam via wifi rathen than tethring via Usb ... is there any better solution?? Am I right to switch to the second solution ... !!