# iPhone camera module connection type

Tags: camera, picamera

I am trying to see if there is any possible way to adapt these salvaged iPhone camera modules to be usable on any Raspberry pi computer.

If anyone is familiar with these and has had any success with them outside of the iPhone, please share your story.

I have included a photo of the small lot I have and it seems there are different model types.

There is also a front-facing camera, mic, and proximity sensor combo that seems to have different connection types.

One of the rear-facing cameras has an LED "flashlight" attached to it. I forget what model this came from.

I know there are a bunch of connector converter interfaces that might fit this, but I'm not sure if it's adaptable to USB or RPi camera ports.

Trying to upload an image from my phone errors, so I may need to update later with a photo if needed.ne errors, so I may need to update later with a  photo if needed.

Comment: Simple; all you need to do is get a technical specification, design a hardware interface and write a kernel driver.

Comment: Oh good. That should be easy enough.... ...  I should have known. It's Apple.  If they were the makers of the Raspberry Pi,   they'd have a model called proPi-etary.

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an old phone or your daily driver as the camera feed for Rpi.
Reference link: [Camera input from phone to Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38902/camera-input-from-phone-to-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Link-only answer. Include the relevant info from the link in your answer.