# Using Android Phone as Webcam via USB to use Zoom or Google Meet

Tags: camera, android, webcam

People have been asking for help to be able to purchase a tablet or a computer that they can use for online classes. Most people here in the Philippines don't have the means to buy any of it. However, most people have android phones.

I am setting up a raspberry pi sample of using an android phone as a camera and mic and install it in a raspberry pi 4B using a USB cable and as a webcam.

The final setup will be given and downloadable for free to those who will need it. So rather than buying expensive tablets, they can just use their raspberry pi to do their classes and be able to have a PC that they can use in the meantime.

Can anyone tell me how to do such a setup? I was able to make an IP camera setup... however, most people here don't even have internet in their homes. That's the reason why I need it to be setup as a webcam that's directly connected to the PI.

Thank you very much and rest assured your help with this will be able to help thousands of young students in my country and allow them to learn... specially in this pandemic.

Comment: The most important part of this questions is whether there is a way to make an Android phone connect as a *generic USB webcam* -- glancing around, I think there is not, as all the apps I found for streaming the camera over USB require a custom client on the connected computer, and they are unlikely to provide one that will work on a Pi.  The closest chance I found in a few casual minutes was this: https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam since it has a linux client.  I did not take the next step which would be to determine if that client can be run on a Pi in Raspbian/RpiOS.

Comment: To clarify: If the phone can act as a *generic USB webcam*, you would not need any special software on the Pi.  But again, a casual search implies no one has done this... Meaning if you don't find an app who's client will run on a Pi you are out of luck WRT a direct USB connection.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it can be done... If anyone ever thought of programming it...is another question. If we can do this...we can help a lot! Thanks

Comment: Dmitry's post (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117403/5538) from the duplicate question here seems to indicate that you *can* make a phone act like a generic USB webcam, which provides an answer to this question.